# pass initial data into a singleton factory in dart

Tags: dart

I would like to pass some initial information into a singleton in dart.
Unfortunately, the information I like to access is null (see dartpad output below)
It seems like I get a new instance of my object and not the singleton but I can not wrap my head around it. Any idea?

```
ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData
ElmCommandProvider._internal()
ElmCommandProvider._init
ElmCommandProvider()
null
```

This is the code which can be pasted in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/dart)

```
class Command {
  Command(this.i);
  final int i;
}

class MetaData {
  MetaData(this.i);
  final int i;
}

class ElmCommandProvider {
  List<Command> commandsList;
  bool _lock = false;

  static Map<String, MetaData> _metaDataPool;

  factory ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData(Map<String, MetaData> metaDataPool) {
    print('ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData');
    assert(!_singleton._lock, "it's a singleton that can't re-defined");
    ElmCommandProvider._metaDataPool = metaDataPool;
    _singleton._lock = true;
    ElmCommandProvider._init();
    return _singleton;
  }

  factory ElmCommandProvider() {
    print('ElmCommandProvider()');
    return _singleton;
  }

  static final ElmCommandProvider _singleton =
      new ElmCommandProvider._internal();

  ElmCommandProvider._internal() {
    print('ElmCommandProvider._internal()');
  }
  ElmCommandProvider._init() {
    print('ElmCommandProvider._init');
    commandsList =
        _metaDataPool.values.map((bloc) => Command(bloc.i)).toList();
    
  }
}

void main() {
  ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData({'1': MetaData(1), '2': MetaData(2)});
  print( ElmCommandProvider().commandsList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_init()` should not be a constructor. Or at least there is no need for it to be one and it's confusing you. It should be changed to a static method or a private instance method.

When you do `commandsList=` in `ElmCommandProvider._init()`, `commandsList` is referring to the `commandsList` instance variable in the **new** `ElmCommandProvider` object you're creating with the constructor. You likely actually mean to modify the singleton's `commandsList` so you should have been doing `singleton.commandsList =` instead of just `commandsList =`.

Example working code with static method:

```dart
class Command {
  Command(this.i);
  final int i;
}

class MetaData {
  MetaData(this.i);
  final int i;
}

class ElmCommandProvider {
  List<Command> commandsList;
  bool _lock = false;

  static Map<String, MetaData> _metaDataPool;

  factory ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData(Map<String, MetaData> metaDataPool) {
    print('ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData');
    assert(!_singleton._lock, "it's a singleton that can't re-defined");
    ElmCommandProvider._metaDataPool = metaDataPool;
    _singleton._lock = true;
    _init();
    return _singleton;
  }

  factory ElmCommandProvider() {
    print('ElmCommandProvider()');
    return _singleton;
  }

  static final ElmCommandProvider _singleton =
      new ElmCommandProvider._internal();

  ElmCommandProvider._internal() {
    print('ElmCommandProvider._internal()');
  }
  static _init() {
    print('ElmCommandProvider._init');
    _singleton.commandsList =
        _metaDataPool.values.map((bloc) => Command(bloc.i)).toList();
    
  }
}

void main() {
  ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData({'1': MetaData(1), '2': MetaData(2)});
  print( ElmCommandProvider().commandsList);
}
```

Example working code with private instance method:

```dart
class Command {
  Command(this.i);
  final int i;
}

class MetaData {
  MetaData(this.i);
  final int i;
}

class ElmCommandProvider {
  List<Command> commandsList;
  bool _lock = false;

  static Map<String, MetaData> _metaDataPool;

  factory ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData(Map<String, MetaData> metaDataPool) {
    print('ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData');
    assert(!_singleton._lock, "it's a singleton that can't re-defined");
    ElmCommandProvider._metaDataPool = metaDataPool;
    _singleton._lock = true;
    _singleton._init();
    return _singleton;
  }

  factory ElmCommandProvider() {
    print('ElmCommandProvider()');
    return _singleton;
  }

  static final ElmCommandProvider _singleton =
      new ElmCommandProvider._internal();

  ElmCommandProvider._internal() {
    print('ElmCommandProvider._internal()');
  }
  void _init() {
    print('ElmCommandProvider._init');
    commandsList =
        _metaDataPool.values.map((bloc) => Command(bloc.i)).toList();
    
  }
}

void main() {
  ElmCommandProvider.fromMetaData({'1': MetaData(1), '2': MetaData(2)});
  print( ElmCommandProvider().commandsList);
}
```